# coldfusion object v10 vs. v9

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

This piece of code works on CF10, but NOT on CF9. Can anyone give me insight as to why?

The CF9 ERROR reads:

```
Invalid CFML construct found on line 2 at column 18.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
{
```

The CODE:

```
<cfscript>
CompanyobjData = {
  'CustomerID' : 'a',
  'CUSTOMERNAME1' : 'b',
  'CUSTOMERADDRESS1' : 'c',
  'CUSTOMERADDRESS2' : 'd',
  'CITY' : 'e',
  'ST' : 'f',
  'ZIP' : 'g',
  'PHONE' : 'h',
  'DEFAULTTERM' : 'i'
};
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#CompanyobjData#" >
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `:` separator is only supported from CF10, use `=` signs instead.

Comment: I left that second set of quotes just for you Leigh :D

Comment: Lol, my mental compiler kept complaining about asymmetrical quotes ;-)

Comment: Shouldn't have had the double quotes at all. :P

Comment: I think the quotes provide better emphasis. But at least you kept things symmetrical ;-)